# GraphQL Cannot read property 'query' of undefined

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, postgraphile

I cannot work out why I would get a query undefined when I know my definitions are correct. `graphiQL` is picking up my schemes without problems:

[image]

Auto complete works fine:

[image: Before hitting alt+enter]

[image]

*After hitting `ctrl+enter` all the fields are entered, see above.*

Then I execute the query and I'll get:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot read property 'query' of undefined",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 1,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "allAwards"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "allAwards": null
  }
}
```

## npm run graphql

```
"graphql": "nodemon -r dotenv/config --experimental-modules --inspect=[9222] graphql_server.js",
```

## graphql_server.js

```
import express from 'express'
import pg from 'pg'
import graphqlHTTP from 'express-graphql'
import PAS from 'postgraphile-apollo-server'
import AP from 'apollo-server-express'

const { makeSchemaAndPlugin } = PAS
const { ApolloServer } = AP

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
const dbHost = process.env.DB_HOST
const dbPort = process.env.DB_PORT
const dbName = process.env.DB_NAME
const dbUser = process.env.DB_USER
const dbPwd = process.env.DB_PWD
const dbUrl = dbPwd
  ? `postgres://${dbUser}:${dbPwd}@${dbHost}:${dbPort}/${dbName}`
  : `postgres://${dbHost}:${dbPort}/${dbName}`

const pgPool = new pg.Pool({
  connectionString: dbUrl,
})

async function main() {
  const { schema, plugin } = await makeSchemaAndPlugin(
    pgPool,
    'public', // PostgreSQL schema to use
    {
      // PostGraphile options, see:
      // https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/usage-library/
    }
  )

  const server = new ApolloServer({
    schema,
    plugins: [plugin],
  })
  const app = express()

  app.use(
    '/graphql',
    graphqlHTTP({
      schema: schema,
      graphiql: true,
    })
  )

  server.applyMiddleware({ app })

  app.listen({ port: 4000 }, () => console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:4000${server.graphqlPath}`))
}

main().catch(e => {
  console.error(e)
  process.exit(1)
})
```

There are 2 rows currently in psql db for awards as well

[image]

Comment: Why are you using `express-graphql` on top of Apollo? if you need GraphiQL, Apollo already exposes a GraphQL Playground interface which does everything that GraphiQL does plus more. It's possible that by applying *both* middleware, you're creating some unexpected conflict. Try removing `express-graphql` first.

Comment: Ye, this was the reason why. I dislike playground as it doesn't have autocomplete. i wish it did :( I did actually remove this and indeed it fixed it, but now I'm at a bit of a roadblock

Comment: GraphQL Playground does have autocomplete? Works just fine [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/apollo-server).

Comment: I've seen autocomplete break before, usually because something is off with the schema and the introspection query returns something unexpected. You can check the console in the browser and see if there's an error shown in those cases.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, its actually autocomplete on the fields, so the `edge > node > *` fields that I was after auto completing, all of them. But yes, I think your answer is onto the real problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not utilize middleware from both `express-graphql` and `apollo-server` in your express application. Because `postgraphile-apollo-server` works explicitly with ApolloServer, drop `express-graphql` altogether. Having both middleware is likely to cause unexpected issues since they listen on the same paths.

Apollo has abandoned GraphiQL in favor of GraphQL Playground. If you want to use GraphiQL with Apollo, you can use a package like [express-graphiql-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-graphiql-middleware).

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to use graphqil over the playground?

Comment: @JamieHutber [Not with just Apollo](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/commit/e4a6e873f80fc1fcc2cf06808a122b1550cbde42). You can always try something like [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-graphiql-middleware) which should just serve GraphiQL on the designated path without touching anything else.

Comment: Nailed it, add that to the answer and I will accept in a heart beat :D thank you sir.

Comment: Now its this one I need to fix lol https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56728281/react-nextjs-wont-compile-when-using-react-apollo